# Show specific viewcontroller after Application started

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, uistoryboard

i want to show uo a viewcontroller connected via a seque from the first view of the rootviewcontroller which is a navigation controller. I tried the following code. But it doesnt work for me : `[_window.rootViewController.navigationController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLoginScreen" sender:self];`

What i am doing wrong : 
Here is a screen shot of my storyboard connections :

[click here](http://imageshack.us/f/820/bildschirmfoto20121108u.png/)

I want to show the MainViewController after startup.

Comment: I think there is a bit problem with your storyboard as well. Why would you put 2 navigation controllers to push through one view controller to another?

Comment: Hmm I'm a bit old fashioned. If i were you I would put a NavigationController object onto an App Delegate and use it whenever I wanted to push from one viewcontroller to another. (Even if it is modal.)

Comment: Can you then please tell me how i can accsess the first viewcontroller of my navigationcontroller inside my appdelegate ... ? Something like [_window.rootviewcontroller firstViewController] :/ ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779808/how-to-use-custom-navigationcontroller-in-appdelegate-by-using-a-storyboard please refer this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something along the following lines:

```
MainViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ShowLoginScreen"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

You need to obtain a reference to the view controller via the storyboard.

Comment: i thought i just can call my rootviewcontrollers navigationcontroller and then perform a seque with identifier .. i thing it would be the easist way.