# Get storyboard-defined UINavigationController from AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

In storyboard, I have an introductory view controller which fades to a UINavigationController.

```
      |   |      |   |
   -> |   |  ->  |   |     
      |   |      |   |
     ViewCtrl   NavCtrl
```

I would like to get a reference to the navigation controller from the app delegate (like the @Guillaume answer does in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779808/how-to-use-custom-navigationcontroller-in-appdelegate-by-using-a-storyboard)).

Here's how I'm trying to access it:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.window.rootViewController.navigationController;
```

But the navigation controller is nil.

Any notion why the navController is nil or what I can do to get a reference to it?

Comment: Have you set the Storyboard ID for your UINavigationController? If not, you should do that in your Storyboard. After that, you don't need all of that to access your navigation controller. You would just need [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myID"]. I'm assuming your calling that from your view controller. To access a navigation controller like you wanted, that would be possible only if your rootViewController were within a UINavigationController.

Comment: Thanks @rocir! That looks promising. My only objection is that there should already be a UINavigationController instantiated, and I'd like to get a reference to that one. I don't think I want to instantiate a second nav controller.

Comment: But this way you're doing you won't make it because your rootViewController isn't within a UINavigationController. Also, at this point, UIViewController wasn't instantiated yet. So you have any segue connecting these two view controllers?

Comment: The code trying to access the nav controller doesn't run until a few controllers have been pushed to the nav controller (so it will have been instantiated). Any idea how @Guillaume got it to work in the example I linked to in the question?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't access it from your ViewCtrl because it isn't within NavCtrl. That could work in an app that has the rootViewController inside a navigation controller. I'm not sure if his code works in this way. If you *REALLY* want to do in this way, what I would suggest is to create a property in the AppDelegate (like navigationController) and set it once you initialize it for the first time. After that you just access this property to get it.

Comment: I think that leaves me with the initial problem - to set a property in my app delegate, I need a reference to the navigation controller.

Comment: Or still, you could reverse and make your navigation controller you rootViewController. Then you push the introductory view controller just once and never more (in future app launches you don't push it anymore). The you can access the navigation controller as being the root view controller.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36053/discussion-between-rocir-and-bbrame)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                         bundle: nil];

UINavigationController *controller = (UINavigationController*)[mainStoryboard 
                    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"<Controller ID>"];
```

You specify the controller identifier for your navigation controller in the attributes inspector of the navigation controller.

Comment: It is in the "identity Inspector" (3rd from left).

Comment: this will return a new instance of the navigation controller every time

Comment: @MohamedElkassas exactly. getting any controller from storyboard is "instantiating" new object every time. there's no such thing as "shared instance" from the storyboard. if you want such shared instance, you should instantiate it once on the appdelegate, and then access it from everywhere in your app through the appdelegate.

Comment: this will return a new instance of the navigation controller every time

Answer (score 2):

So Arsen's solution looks nice but I didnt know how to get the name of my storyboard lol. What worked for me was

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController*)_window.rootViewController;
AVDashboardViewController *dashBoardViewController =
(AVDashboardViewController*)[navigationController.viewControllers  objectAtIndex:1];//since on index 0 I have my login screen and index 1 is the home screen
```

Getting the NavigationController's reference on the AppDelegate might seem like bad coding practice, but in my case I needed it because it is where the

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

is located, which is one of the methods called when a Notification is received. I also struggled on how to update the navigation controller once I got the message, so maybe off topic but here is a free tip:

```
UIBarButtonItem *notiButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Received push!" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:nil];

[[dashBoardViewController navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:notiButton animated:YES];

[navigationController popToViewController:dashBoardViewController animated:YES];
```

Hope it helps!